# Заполнить DataFrame данными из другого DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть DataFrame *df_heroes* и *df_train*, в каждом из которых есть параметр *hero_id*. Я хочу пройти по *df_heroes*, добавляя в пока не существующую колонку *hero_roles* данные *roles* с таким же *hero_id* из фрейма *df_heroes*.
Я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
for row in df_train.itertuples(index = False):
    row['hero_roles'] = df_heroes.loc[df_heroes["hero_id"]==row["hero_id"]].values["roles"]
```

Но при этом я получаю ошибку:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    3077             try:
> -> 3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>    3079             except KeyError:
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'hero_id'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-10-2c33f244f191> in <module>
>       1 for row in df_train.itertuples(index = False):
> ----> 2     row['hero_roles'] = df_heroes.loc[df_heroes["hero_id"]==row["hero_id"]].values["roles"]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
>    2686             return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
>    2687         else:
> -> 2688             return self._getitem_column(key)
>    2689 
>    2690     def _getitem_column(self, key):
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _getitem_column(self, key)
>    2693         # get column
>    2694         if self.columns.is_unique:
> -> 2695             return self._get_item_cache(key)
>    2696 
>    2697         # duplicate columns & possible reduce dimensionality
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in _get_item_cache(self, item)
>    2487         res = cache.get(item)
>    2488         if res is None:
> -> 2489             values = self._data.get(item)
>    2490             res = self._box_item_values(item, values)
>    2491             cache[item] = res
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py in get(self, item, fastpath)
>    4113 
>    4114             if not isna(item):
> -> 4115                 loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
>    4116             else:
>    4117                 indexer = np.arange(len(self.items))[isna(self.items)]
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
>    3078                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
>    3079             except KeyError:
> -> 3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
>    3081 
>    3082         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
>
> KeyError: 'hero_id'
> ```

Как мне сделать так, что бы мой код работал?

Ссылка на пример данных: https://yadi.sk/d/ZAzQifMGwZphHg

Comment: Можете привести небольшие (3-5 строк) примеры входных данных (в таком виде, чтобы данные можно было скопировать/скачать) и выходной датасет (то что вы хотите получить на выходе)? [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060)

Comment: @MaxU Добавил примеры (хотя я.диск, наверное, не лучшее решение)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
df_train.loc[:, 'hero_roles'] = df_train['hero_id'].map(df_heroes.set_index('hero_id')['roles'])
```

или так:

```
df_train = df_train.merge(df_heroes[['hero_id','roles']], on='hero_id', how='left')
```

---

Проверка на предоставленных данных:

```
df_heroes = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\dota2_heroes.csv')
df_train = pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\dota2_skill_train.csv')

df_train = df_train.merge(df_heroes[['hero_id','roles']], on='hero_id', how='left')
```

Результат:

```
In [54]: df_train[['hero_id','roles']]
Out[54]:
       hero_id                                                   roles
0           90             ['Support', 'Nuker', 'Disabler', 'Jungler']
1            5             ['Support', 'Disabler', 'Nuker', 'Jungler']
2           81  ['Carry', 'Disabler', 'Durable', 'Pusher', 'Initiat...
3           74      ['Carry', 'Nuker', 'Disabler', 'Escape', 'Pusher']
4           14           ['Disabler', 'Initiator', 'Durable', 'Nuker']
5           61                  ['Carry', 'Pusher', 'Escape', 'Nuker']
6          114            ['Carry', 'Escape', 'Disabler', 'Initiator']
7           85             ['Support', 'Durable', 'Disabler', 'Nuker']
8           62                                     ['Escape', 'Nuker']
9           64              ['Support', 'Nuker', 'Pusher', 'Disabler']
...        ...                                                     ...
99861       14           ['Disabler', 'Initiator', 'Durable', 'Nuker']
99862       62                                     ['Escape', 'Nuker']
99863      114            ['Carry', 'Escape', 'Disabler', 'Initiator']
99864       85             ['Support', 'Durable', 'Disabler', 'Nuker']
99865        4  ['Carry', 'Disabler', 'Jungler', 'Nuker', 'Initiator']
99866       70             ['Carry', 'Jungler', 'Durable', 'Disabler']
99867       36               ['Carry', 'Nuker', 'Durable', 'Disabler']
99868       48                            ['Carry', 'Nuker', 'Pusher']
99869      111              ['Support', 'Nuker', 'Disabler', 'Escape']
99870      105                                   ['Nuker', 'Disabler']

[99871 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: В первом случае я получаю аналогичную ошибку, во втором - KeyError: "['hero_id'] not in index". Возможно, играет роль то, что в df_train параметр hero_id не уникален?

Comment: @biryulin04, проверил оба решения на ваших данных - все работает. Смотрите пример и результат в ответе...